# Git Workflow for file-converting scripts

Tags: git

I am currently developing a script that should convert files in a git repository from an "old format" to a "new format". So, based on, let's call it commit 0 (the latest one that contains the old format files) my script converts the files, and I can commit version 1.
Now, after the script evolved, I want to commit version 2 of the files in new format. For the script to work, I have to revert my local files to commit 0. But: I want to commit my changes, as if I just adjusted the files from version 1 a bit.

What is the best Workflow to achieve this? Which git commands allow me to commit a filetree that was created by altering an old version, as if it was based on the latest commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout files from the old commit, convert and commit:

```
# We're at the $COMMIT_1
git checkout $COMMIT_0 -- \*
# convert *
git commit -a
```

Comment: Well, they both initiate a merge. This is not what I wanted, because I definitely don't want to keep the old script results. Merging them with the newer results create broken hybrid files.

Comment: I updated the answer. Now it's much simpler except that you may need to list files to restore.

Comment: Works like a charm. But I think you should have left the other answers as well, so that people, who search for that, can also find it.

Comment: May be. The link [edited…](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45557799/revisions) gives access to all revisions.